# Groebner basis with parameters

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, groebner-bases

I need to compute a Groebner basis of a polynomial system with parameters.
The only recent results I found is Groebner cover:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717110000970

Are there any more advanced algorithms for the study of parametric polynomial systems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mathscinet mentions some 30 papers citing the paper you mention, among which the following looks like potentially relevant:

[Kapur, Deepak (1-NM-C); Sun, Yao (PRC-ASBJ-MML); Wang, Dingkang (PRC-ASBJ-MML)
An efficient algorithm for computing a comprehensive Gröbner system of a parametric polynomial system. (English summary)
J. Symbolic Comput. 49 (2013), 27–44.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717111002082)

[Dehghani Darmian, Mahdi (IR-TEH-SMC); Hashemi, Amir (IR-IUT)
Parametric FGLM algorithm. (English summary)
J. Symbolic Comput. 82 (2017), 38–56.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717116301705)

[Hashemi, Amir (IR-IUT); Kazemi, Mahsa (IR-IUT)
Parametric standard bases and their applications. (English summary) Computer algebra in scientific computing, 179–196,
Lecture Notes in Comput. Sci., 11661, Springer, Cham, 2019.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-26831-2_13)

[Ponleitner, Bettina (A-WIENM); Schichl, Hermann (A-WIENM)
Exclusion regions for parameter-dependent systems of equations. (English summary)
J. Global Optim. 81 (2021), no. 3, 621–644.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10898-021-01082-3)